# How the payment system works ? ( new with Magento )

Tags: magento2, shipping, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

So, I come to you because I have just started on Magento, my concern right now is that I still can not understand how the `payment` system on this `CMS` works.
I would like to know after the customer has chosen a payment method what happens, then how we are supposed to retrieve his`payment` on the site. for example, we choose to use PayPal or bank transfer.

If anyone could enlighten me on the subject it would be really cool of him.

Thank you

Comment: See this link : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html

Comment: can you enlighten me at the level of the steps? For example, I just ordered and I chose to pay by credit card, I receive an email telling me that I would receive a tracking email and that's where I'm lost because there is still no question of payment.